# Android - Why the latest version of my app is deployed but cannot show on play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

When i deployed a newer version of my android app on google play store (e.g. v1.17), but Google Play Store App in my device still display old version (v1.16) cause that i cannot update it from my device.
But i can login the Play Store from PC, and see the latest version. Then i can update the app to latest version through PC Google Play Store.

How can let play store always show the latest app version in the device?
(even if i try to clear data / clear cache for google play service, it still displays old version.)

Thanks.

Comment: i think that you must wait google play support to accept your application and after that your app will automatically update if evrything is correct and you don`t corrupt or some bad data in your app of course :)

Comment: because i found out the app is shown older version which version is one week ago on Google Play Store in some mobile device :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that always fill-in the `what's news` change log when upload newer app version, it seem be easy to let play store show the latest app version faster in the device.

Answer (score 1):

just wait a couple of hours. It is highly automated, the whole process. personally it takes 3-4 hours to see my app on google play store on my device